# TFS 2010 Team Foundation services are not available from server <host>. Unable to connect to the remote server

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfs

The system administrators had to do a restore of a number of servers in our network, one of which was our TFS Server and Database.

However, we have found that our Visual Studio IDEs are not able to connect, and is coming back with the message " Team Foundation services are not available from server . Unable to connect to the remote server".

Looking at the TFS Admin Console, I can see that the Project Collections are there and there is a message saying they are online.

We have tried restarting services and dropping caches, but nothing seems to work!

Does anyone have any bright ideas?

Comment: What happens if you visit the web portal?

Comment: Not sure. I not away if any one has tried it yet

Comment: The web in the IIS is started?

Comment: web portal does not work either and iis and application pools are running